# как отбросить число до запятой в пайтоне? 0,05 чтобы стало 05

Tags: python, числа

как отбросить число до запятой в пайтоне?
0,05 чтобы стало 05

Comment: `str(n).split(',')[1]`

Answer (score 3):

Можно преобразовать число в строку и использовать метод `split`:

```
x = 0.05
after_comma = str(x).split('.')[1]
print(after_comma)
```